# Trying to understand how the math behind for Greedy Modularity Algorithm works

Tags: algorithm, math, partition, greedy, modularity

I'm using the [greedy modularity algorithm from networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities.html) in a project and I need to dissect [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0408187.pdf) of this algorithm.

From what I understand, you begin the algorithm putting every vertex into a community of one, calculating the modularity for the network using this separation into communities and then changing the network and incrementing the modularity using the algorithm steps in a way that the new modularity of the graph is the modularity of the new separation.

But from reading the paper and doing some calculations it seems that the algorithm doesn't increment enough to give us the modularity of the new separation.

Starting the algorithm, using equation (7) we will have

[image]

After the first increment (joining two vertices that are connected), if we calculate Q by the equation (7) we will have, if the vertices are v1 and v2 and the community they are in is called i

[image]

And if we calculate the new modularity using the first increment of the algorithm, we will only have

[image]

Which is definitely different from the previous one. So how is this difference compensated? Am I calculating this wrong?

Comment: This is basically a pure maths question, better asked over on the [math.se] site.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks! I'll ask there!